# How to get the last day of the previous month in Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have the following code to get the current day:

```
var month=new Array(12);
month[0]="January";
month[1]="February";
month[2]="March";
month[3]="April";
month[4]="May";
month[5]="June";
month[6]="July";
month[7]="August";
month[8]="September";
month[9]="October";
month[10]="November";
month[11]="December";

var d = new Date();
var curr_date;
if (d.getDate() == 1)
{
    curr_date = d.getDate();
}
else
{
    curr_date = d.getDate() - 1;
}

var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //months are zero based
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var message_day = curr_year + "_" + curr_month + "_" + curr_date;
var sql_day = month[curr_month - 1].substring(0,3) + curr_date.toString() + curr_year.toString();

if (curr_date == "1")
    {
         document.write(sql_day + " " + message_day);
    }
```

This is great for getting the current day, but now i need to get the last day of the last month if it is the beginning of a new month.

right now this will produce:

```
Feb12012 2012_2_1
```

but what i need output is:

```
Jan312012 2012_1_31
```

Thanks

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
var d=new Date(); // current date
d.setDate(1); // going to 1st of the month
d.setHours(-1); // going to last hour before this date even started.
```

now `d` contains the last date of the previous month. `d.getMonth()` and `d.getDate()` will reflect it.

This should work on any date api that wraps c `time.h`.

Comment: Slicker than oil!  :-)

Comment: Simple is sexy!

Comment: I just used this solution and it works well, except you need to be careful with timezones if you're going to be using ISO format for the output.  I had to zero-out all of my hours, minutes and seconds to make sure that when converted into ISO format it showed the correct dates....

Comment: Setting day 0 of current month you get last day of previous month.

Answer (score 36):

This works perfectly for me:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(0);
```

**date** now contains the last day of the previous month.

Comment: Missing `d.setHours(-1);` // going to last hour before this date even started.

Comment: this solution failed for me when the last date of last month is 31

Comment: The other comments are misleading. This method works; you just have to include the time and omit the timezone designator ('Z') if you are setting the date explicitly. Examples:

new Date('2023-01-15T00:00:00.000') - Works,
new Date('2023-01-15T00:00') - Works,
new Date('2023-01-15T00:00:00.000Z') - Does not work,
new Date('2023-01-15') - Does not work

Answer (score 1):

```
var lastdayoflastmonth = new Date();
lastdayoflastmonth.setMonth(lastdayoflastmonth.getMonth(), 0);
var firstdayoflastmonth = new Date();
firstdayoflastmonth.setDate(1);
firstdayoflastmonth.setMonth(firstdayoflastmonth.getMonth()-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the answers I was get most of them were failing to capture 31 in the May so I tried out several options and these are the ones I came up with. Hope, some may find this useful.

```
const today = new Date()
const lastMonth = today.getMonth() === 0 ? 11 : today.getMonth() - 1
const year = lastMonth === 0 ? today.getFullYear - 1 : today.getFullYear

const lastDayOfLastMonth = new Date(year, lastMonth + 1, 0).getDate()
const lastDateTimeOfLastMonth = new Date(year, lastMonth + 1, 1)
const lastDateOfLastMonth = new Date(year, lastMonth + 1, 0).toLocaleDateString()

console.log(lastDayOfLastMonth) // eg 31
console.log(lastDateTimeOfLastMonth) // eg 2021-05-31T16:00:00.000Z
console.log(lastDateOfLastMonth) // eg 31/05/2021
```

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract one from the day-of-month:

```
 var today = new Date();
 var yesterday = new Date().setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
```

If the "date" property (the day-of-month) is 1, then setting it to zero will give you a date representing the last day of the previous month. Your code was pretty close already; you could just construct a new Date instance:

```
 if (d.getDate() === 1)
    curr_date = new Date().setDate(0).getDate();
```

In fact you don't even need an "if" statement:

```
 curr_date = new Date().setDate( d.getDate() - 1 ).getDate();
```

and that'll work for any day of the month.

Comment: for some reason, i am not getting the output i expect: http://jsfiddle.net/gT6eZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
function dateLastMonth() {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setDate(0);
            return date.getDate().toString() + '/' + date.getMonth().toString() + '/' + date.getFullYear().toString();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const today = new Date();
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 0, 0,0,0,0)).toISOString()
console.log(date)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

```
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];                                       
let today = new Date();
let dd = today.getDate();

let mm = today.getMonth()+1;
let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10) 
{
    dd='0'+dd; 
} 
if(mm<10) 
{
    mm='0'+mm;
} 
dd = new Date(yyyy, mm-1, 0).getDate(); 

let month = '';                     
mm == 1 ? month = monthNames[monthNames.length - 1] : month = monthNames[mm-2];                                         
mm == 1 ? yyyy = yyyy - 1 : '';                                                                                 

let lastDay = month+'-'+dd+'-'+yyyy;
```